# A little problem in a proof of a corollary in Huybrechts' book

Tags: complex-geometry

In proof of corollary 1.1.19 in Page 16. In the last paragraph he claims that

> Since $g$ is irreducible and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1}$ is of degree $d-1$, there exist elements $h_1,h_2\in\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}^{n-1},0}[z_1]$ and $0\neq\gamma\in\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}^{n-1},0}$ such that $h_1g+h_2\frac{\partial g}{z_1}=\gamma$

He says it holds from Gauss lemma, but I don't know why. Furthermore, I think there is a typo in the last sentence

> If $g_w$ has a zero $\xi$ of multiplicity $>1$, then $\gamma(\xi)=h_1(\xi,w)g_w(\xi)+h_2(\xi,w)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1}(\xi)=0$

I think it should be $\gamma(w)$? Am I right? Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Comment: Yes you are right $\gamma\in\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}^{n-1},0}
$ therefore it has variable $w$, for the Gauss lemma, I typically treat it as a black box coming from algebra.

Comment: If you really want to see the proof of the Gauss' lemma, see Junjiro Noguchi's wonderful book called Analytic Function Theory of Several Variables, section 2.2 page 41

Comment: @yili Thanks a lot for you comment!